# How to change the RandomForestClassifier in Python scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

How can I change the `RandomForestClassifier` in `scikit-learn` so that instead of holding in each terminal node the classes distribution. I'll go through all the records (in each terminal node) and run a formula such as `linear regression`?

```
# Import the random forest package
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
# Create the random forest object which will include all the parameters
# for the fit
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 1)
#Take the same decision trees and run it on the test data
output = forest.predict(test_data)
```

Comment: Please specify more about what you want, preferably with an example

Comment: I would like to add to each cluster a model. It means, that if RandomForest has 3 terminal nodes: A, B and C. I'll go to all records (in training) that are A and run a linear regression for them. Same for B and C.